# unable to authenticate to azure using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, authentication, scripting, azure-active-directory

we had an azure tenant.
we opened a new one, and passed our users to the new tenant and then added our users to the old tenants as guests.
Passing means that we deleted our users from the first tenant, then we migrated the domain to the new tenant and we created the users with the same properties in the new tenant.

since then every time we try to connect to azure using powershell with the commend Connect-azaccount -TenantId  we get the following error:

```
Unable to acquire token for tenant '***' with error 'SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No account matching the specified username: *** tenantId: *** was found in the cache.'
```

does someone knows hoe to fix this?

thank you

we have tried every thing we found online.
we tries clear-azcontext, deleting the certificated from our machines, deleting powershell and reinstalling, etc...

Comment: the client needs an account on the new tenant.  You are using Windows Authentication for the connection so the client needs an account on new Tenant.  There should be a Group Policy where the uses have Network Account on all machines.  You may be missing the Group Policy on the new domain.

Answer (score 3):

> Unable to acquire token for tenant xxx with error SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No account matching the specified username: xxx tenantId: xxx was found in the cache

The error usually occurs if the user is not present in the tenant you are trying to sign-in.

To check the error in detail, you can try **debugging** like below:

```
$DebugPreference = "Continue"
Connect-AzAccount -TenantID XXXX
```

[image]

Based on the debug details, you can check which Tenant is the user being connected to or any user details.

Try to connect with **Subscription ID** like below:

```
Connect-AzAccount -Subscription SubscriptionID -TenantId TenantID
```

[image]

Check if the user is having MFA enabled and try connecting with Global Admin account. And it might be the scenario where the account might be still cached in the local machine, so try if it works in another machine.

You can also make use of **Device Authentication** like below:

```
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant TenantID -UseDeviceAuthentication
```

Open the browser and enter the code:

[image]

Make sure to **install the Az module** like below:

Initially clear the cache and try to install by setting execution policy

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
Install-Module Az
Import-Module Az
Update-Module -Name Az
```

[image]

Check whether the user account in the Tenant has required permissions to the subscription.

Try to **select the Context** in PowerShell:

```
Get-AzContext -ListAvailable
Select-AzContext -Name Name
```

[image]

Or you can set context to the SubscriptionID by including TenantID:

```
Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscription -Tenant $tenantId | Out-null
```

[image]

**If still the issue persists**, it might be some environment problem while migrating the domain.

Comment: Wow thank you, tried most of it, but I didn’t try the debug option, I will try

Comment: we've tried everything and it still doesnt work.
we dont think its an environment problem because if we try to connect from a different machine, like: different local user, vm etc... it works,we just cant find the problem on our machines.
we are working on macos

Comment: If the issue still persists, please raise an Azure Support Ticket

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem seemed to be related to using a "legacy" account (or whatever they're called). Making and using a new account seemed to resolve the issue for me.